# Show that $\prod _{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$ can be divided wihout remainder in $\prod_{i<j}(i-j)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, products

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a natural numbers,

> show that $\prod _{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$ can be divided wihout remainder in $\prod_{i<j}(i-j)$

I know $\prod \left(x_i-x_j\right)$ is the result of Vandermonde Determinant, so is related with Det?

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of ways to prove this. The most straightforward is induction but there is also a combinatorial proof.

Comment: One of many appearances of this on AoPS: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h56803

Answer (score -1):

Lemma. For every m-coloring vertices of complete graph $K_n$ ($m \leq n$) there are at least $n-m$ edges which have  two vertices of the same color.

proof: Inducion by $n$ - number of vertices. For $n=1,2,3$ this fact is obvious.

$n-1 \rightsquigarrow n$:
Let $V$ is the set of vertices, of $K_n$ ($\left\vert{V}\right\vert= n$).
$m \leq n$ hecnce from pigeonhole principle we have at least two vertices of the same color, for example $a$ and $b$. Consider graph $K_{n-1}$ with set of vertices $V \setminus {a}$. From induction, we have at least $n-1-m$ edges with 2 vetrices of te same color. These edges plus edge $\{a,b\}$ gives us the desirable at least $(n-m)$-element edge set.

Consider now $A := \prod_{i<j} (i-j)$. Note that given difference: $i-j=m$ occurs exactly $n-m$ times in this product ($A$). So $m^{n-m} | A$.

We ask why $m^{n-m} | \prod_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)$ ?
Consider graph $K_n$ of $V=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ veritices. Each vertex $v$ has color from $\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$ $m$-element set and this color equals $\chi(v) := x_v \bmod m$.
From above lemma we have at least $n-m$ egdes with both vertices of the same color, so there are at least $n-m$ pairs: $x_{i_1}-x_{j_1}, \ldots, x_{i_{n-m}}-x_{j_{n-m}}$, such that $m | x_{i_k}-x_{j_k}$, hence $m^{n-m} | \prod_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)$. This is true for all $m = i-j$, so we have $\prod_{i<j} (i-j) | \prod_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)$.

Comment: Careful: the $m^{n-m}$ are not coprime.

Comment: Primality doesn't matter in this proof.

Comment: Then how does your last sentence work?

Comment: All $m$ occurs exactly $n-m$ times in this product. This gives factorisaction of $A$.

Comment: I am speaking of the last sentence of the last paragraph. You cannot use $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ to derive $ab \mid c$ unless you can show that $a$ and $b$ are coprime. And the factors $m$ do not literally occur in the product $\prod_{i<j} \left(x_i-x_j\right)$; their multiples occur, and you do not a-priori know whether some of these multiples are "shared" by different $m$'s.